# Using insertAfter() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml-parsing

I have this XML file,

```
<tour title="Bavaria, Austrian, and the Alps" baseCost="1799.99">
<availability start="2011/03/25" end="2011/9/30"/>
<description>

</description>

<stop day="1">
<title>Munich, Germany. </title>

<description></description>
<latitude>48.15</latitude>
<longitude>11.5833333</longitude>
<hotels>
<hotel name="Europa Hotel" stars="3" premium="0.0"/>
<hotel name="Excelsior Hotel" stars="4" premium="59.99"/>
<hotel name="Grand Hotel" stars="5" premium="199.99"/>
</hotels>

</stop>

<stop day="2">
<title>Garmisch, Germany.</title>

<description>Major destination of the Bavarian alps. Site of a major World Cup ski race.</description>
<latitude>47.5</latitude>
<longitude>11.0833333</longitude>
<hotels>
<hotel name="Europa Hotel" stars="3" premium="0.0"/>
</hotels>
</stop>
```

I have parsed everything I need but the problem is I need to show the output like this,

```
<title name>
 <stop name>
  <hotels names>
 <stop name>
  <hotels names>
```

But the output is coming like this,

```
<title name>
<stops names>
<hotels names>
```

All in one order only, What should I use, insertAfter() or after()?

Here's my jQuery code :
    http://pastebin.com/dmETKi9E

HTML Code:

```
 <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <h2 id="stop"></h2>
    <p id="hotel"></p>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE Tested and Working** The issue is with your HTML. All of the headers are going in with the header, all of the stops are going in the stop, and all the hotels are going in to the hotel, when instead you should be creating a new object for each new item. Look at the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) jquery command. What you are going to want to do is

```
function processXml(xml) {
  var header, stop, hotel;
  $(xml).find("tour").each(function() {
    header = $('<h1 class="header" />');
    header.html($(this).attr("title"));

    $(this).find("stop").each(function() {

      stop = $('<h2 class="stop" />');
      stop.html(($(this).find("title").text()));

      $(this).find("hotel").each(function() {
       hotel = $('<p class="hotel" />');
       hotel.html(($(this).attr("name")));
       stop.append(hotel);
      });

      header.append(stop);
    });
    $('body').append(header);
  });
}
```

You're welcome :)

Comment: I did try this, but it's still not showing the way I want. :/

Comment: What does this give you? I guess I don't fully see what you are trying to get.

Comment: This might clear your doubt, For each stop you must list the title of the stop and a list of the names of the hotels available for that stop.

Comment: I will tag this as homework now. No there's no problem with actual data.

Comment: If you just need tabs I have updated the code above to add a single space for the first sub category then two spaces for the hotels category.

Comment: yes, and thats what the above code does. For each stop it appends the name of the stop then searches all the hotels within that stop. This works the same way as a foreach(){ foreach(){ foreach(){} }}

Comment: I am not getting the output like that. Can my html code have a problem in that case?

Comment: yes, could ya please put your html that is associated to the code in the above question I think i see the issue now.

Comment: But one thing, I getting this error, Uncaught TypeError: Object Bavaria, Austrian, and the Alps has no method 'wrapAll'

Comment: Note: IDs in HTML should be unique. In your case, a good solution would be to replace `id=` with `class=`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that the way youwanted is not well formated xml. Where dose the output go? Why dose it need the special formatting? shouldn't xml also include closing tags?

Comment: The xml is okay actually, it's his implementation of the html that is the issue.